# Jquery focus not working / scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m using the following jquery script to pick a **span** having  a class and focus it

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('span').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('field-validation-error')) {
                $(this).focus();
                $(this).addClass('hello');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

For some reasons the focus won't scroll to the span with the class 'field-validation-error' though it does add the class hello to the element.

The section of the html where this span element reside is as belwo

```
<section id="orderreason">

    <div class="orderrow backgrounddot">
        <ul>
            <li class="widenormal">Please tell us the purpose of your request <span class="asterick">*</span><br>
                (this information is used for statistical purposes only)</li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <p>Please tick any that apply:</p>
            <div class="checkboxrow">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="orderreason"><label>Patient care</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkboxrow">
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="orderreason"><label>Health improvement</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkboxrow">
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="orderreason"><label>Professional development</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkboxrow">
                <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="orderreason"><label>Personal development</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkboxrow">
                <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="orderreason"><label>Management/service improvement</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkboxrow">
                <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="orderreason"><label>Research</label>
            </div>
            <p>Other:</p>
```

```
        <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="orderreason" class="field-validation-error">Please choose a reason or enter other text</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: A span is not focusable, so why would it scroll to that element ?

Comment: Ok- Does focus work with Div having a class?

Comment: Focus really only works with focusable input elements, but as noted in the answer below, adding a tabindex makes an element focusable, but wether the browser will scroll to that element, I don't know, never tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can focus on non-input elements if you give your HTML a `tabindex` attribute like so:

```
<span tabindex="-1"></span>
```

The -1 value makes it so that the element can't be tabbed by the user, but you can programmatically focus it with `el.focus()`

#### Aside

In your implementation, I assume you are creating validation errors. If the validation error occurs next to the input field, why not focus the input field instead of the span? This will have the added benefit of putting the user's cursor where it needs to be to fix the validation issue and deliver an overall better UX.

Comment: The problem is this span is auto generated by the MVC class library and I dont have control over the markup. Can I possibly add a tabindex as an attribute with jquery and then focus it?

Comment: That seems logical... you'll never know until you try though!

Comment: If I understood your aside correctly, what you are saying is if Jquery finds that class than focus on checkbox with the name "orderreason" as in my case

Comment: Exactly. Only I see that your spans are dumped to the bottom of the form?